# PHP How can I sort results with accumulation in the URL by using GET method

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, url

I am working on a sort function which is supposed to sort my results using two different html forms. The first form will be for sorting A-Z, Z-A, Price-Asc, Price-Desc. The second one will be used to show different number of results per page. My question is how can I make these form to work "together". For example on "change" event in the first form I will get something like "?orderBy="A-Z" in the URL. Then If I decide to change the number of results per page I want to keep the current GET parameter in the url and add another one like "?orderBy="A-Z?perPage=12". I saw this kind kind of functionality in a website and I need to make the same one but I am not sure about the concepts and how this thing is supposed to work. Every answer and shared thoughts are much appreciated !

```
<form method="get" id="form_sort">
<select name="sort" onchange="form_sort.submit()">
    <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="price">price</option>
</select>
</form>

<form method="get" id="form_order">
<select name="order" onchange="form_order.submit()">
    <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="asc">ASC</option>
    <option value="desc">DESC</option>
</select>
</form>

<form method="get" id="form_limit">
<select name="limit" onchange="form_limit.submit()">
    <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: post CODE whiplash. We don't build stuff for you, we fix stuff you're building.

Comment: I don't want you to build anything for me I am just asking for advice and some conceptions around how this sorting is supposed to work. But thanks I will have it in mind for the next time.

Comment: whiplash, there's an "edit" button under your question so you can post code. No need to wait for next time. Code makes your question clearer so we can see what you're trying to do. If you discuss tacos with a mexican person you speak spanish. If you talk PHP with code people, you speak code. It's just easier to explain things in their native language.

Comment: i will remove my downvote as soon as you post code :)

Comment: Here is some code..The main problem is that I need to use different forms without any submit buttons, that is why I made the onchange event but I have no idea if this is supposed to work like this.

Comment: Alright whiplash, +1, but still, I would like to give you a definitive answer and in order to do that you will have to post the PHP that handles these forms and the javascript that submits the forms. Ultimately the answer is, combine the forms into a single form and combine the PHP into a single file that can handle all three forms at once. If you want a more spcific answer, please post the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: I have found one solution for my problem. I am using hidden input in the first form which has a value attribute equal to the GET parameter that I am sending from the second form. By doing this when I submit the first form I wont lose anything.

Answer (score 0):

A form will automatically build a query string for you (using GET). If you can keep the `selected` values selected when the page loads, then every time you update the form the same values will remain selected.

Here's an example:

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
        <option value="name"<?=isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']=='name' ? ' selected' : ''?>>name</option>
        <option value="price"<?=isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']=='price' ? ' selected' : ''?>>price</option>
    </select>
    <select name="order">
        <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
        <option value="asc"<?=isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order']=='asc' ? ' selected' : ''?>>ASC</option>
        <option value="desc"<?=isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order']=='desc' ? ' selected' : ''?>>DESC</option>
    </select>
    <select name="limit">
        <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
        <option value="1"<?=isset($_GET['limit']) && $_GET['limit']==1 ? ' selected' : ''?>>1</option>
        <option value="2"<?=isset($_GET['limit']) && $_GET['limit']==2 ? ' selected' : ''?>>2</option>
        <option value="3"<?=isset($_GET['limit']) && $_GET['limit']==3 ? ' selected' : ''?>>3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: i'm not entirely sure this is the answer he was looking for as he mentions having 2 seperate forms.